# I can't use user.save command. rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm japanese high school children.
ih you know the cause,please help me.

Now I can't use user.save command

user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

20140831002057_add_password_digest_to_users.rb  file

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

I type

```
User.create(name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org")
```

after that

```
user.save
```

I can't use this command.
if you know the cause please help me.

(when I use

```
User.create(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com", password: "foobar",             
password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

I can't use this command...)

Comment: user.errors will tell you why the save failed (if it's a validation error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `create` you don't need `save` after that, or you could write:

```
user = User.new(name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org")
user.save
```

also `User` != `user`

Comment: I understand the cause why I can't use [user.save]command 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> **create method**: Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

It is easy to understand if you read the source code.

```
def create(attributes = nil, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, &block)
    object.save   # it has been saved
    object
  end
end
```

So if you create an object by 'created' method, you doesn't need to save it.

Answer (score 0):

**Convention**

Looks to me like you've not got the `user` variable set, although that wouldn't explain the `create` method not firing.

As mentioned by `IS04`, this is what you need in your `users` controller:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
   end
end
```

This is the accepted ([conventional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)) way of creating new records in a rails app. You'll also be best looking into the role of [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in Rails 4, too. I'm not sure how up to date Hartl's tutorial is; last time I heard, he was developing with Rails 3, which is different syntax to Rails 4

Also, notice how we're saving a `@user` variable (not the pure `Model` object)? This is *very* important because it means that you're able to manipulate the data as part of the variable -- if you just submit the data to your model, you're going to end up with a series of data objects which you won't be able to change / manipulate at all.

--

**Create**

When you are calling your `User.create`, the problem you have is you're not catching the response. This means you won't be able to tell the problem.

I'd recommend the following (I presume you're calling this from a controller, and not the `rails console`):

```
user = User.create(name: "test", email: "test@test.com", password: "testest", password_confirmation: "testest")
Rails.logger.info(user.errors.full_messages.inspect()) unless user.save
```

This will show you which errors have been captured.

The bottom line is I believe you'll have a problem with your `has_secure_password` call. I've not used this extensively before, so I don't consider myself the right person to ask about it; but it would make sense if this was not working.

If you use the error output above (will show in your console), you'll be able to discern what the error really is, allowing you to be more specific with your question